# Multiple subscriptions for one user (IOS, Android)

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, google-play-services, subscription, in-app-subscription

we are a live-broadcasting app and here's the question we would like to check.

We are now planning a new subscription mechanism. We would like to let every user subscribe multiple similar service at the same time. Under each service, there's different offer. For example:

Service A

- plan a
- plan b

Service B

- plan a
- plan b

// more services...

Our problem is that we are planing to provide a lot of services(more than 10000), and the amount might exceed the product limit.

So our plan B is to try to create a Service Pool, and dispatch the service group to different service for each user dynamically.

For example:

Actual Services: 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 10000
and the Pool has Service A, B, ... Z

When a user subscribe Service A, it can specify the actual service he want, such as A(12) with plan a.
When the user want to subscribe more services, it will use the one of the remaining B, C ... Z, and specify the actual service again, for example, C(5) with plan b.

We would like to know if this method can be approved by Apple/Google?
Is there any other best practice recommended?